# GraphQL scheme based permissions

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo

I am building a GraphQL Server in Node and am tackling the permission subject. I made a research and most of the recommendations is to place this logic somewhere in resolvers.

I would rather like it to be able to place the permission checking as a middleware step, that is, before it reaches a corresponding resolver(s). This would have several advantages, like:
 - authorisation logic is centralised and reused by all resolvers 
 - resolver logic is much cleaner and straight forward

Opinions about this approach?
Any existing libraries to support GraphQL scheme-based permission validation

Comment: granulation - per field access, some limits (per plan) - keystonejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GraphQL.js doesn't natively support "middleware" for resolvers -- since they're functions, you can just wrap them with whatever additional functions to add logic without repeating yourself. That said, you can add [graphql-middleware](https://github.com/prisma-labs/graphql-middleware) for a nicer API for adding logic to multiple resolvers. If you use `graphql-middleware`, you can add [graphql-shield](https://github.com/maticzav/graphql-shield) which specifically deals with authorization.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [schema-directives](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/schema-directives/) which are more natural to graphql

here is a package that might help you [graphql-directive-auth](https://github.com/graphql-community/graphql-directive-auth)